# Approximate average answer to time spent working at the current job

Tags: stochastic-processes

Suppose that the distribution of time at a **single** job is a **gamma** distribution with a mean of $5$ years and a standard deviation of $2$ years, and suppose that the times at **successive** jobs are **i.i.d.** random variables. Every year the person fills out the survey. What are the **approximate average** answers to the following questions:

a. How long have been working at your **current** job?

b. How long did you work at your **last** job?

**My attempt:** (b) From the given information, the average time spent at the last job should follow gamma distribution with mean $5$ years, so the answer should be $\fbox{5}$ years?

(a) Let $Y_i =$  the time spent at current job. Then it also follows gamma distribution, so $E(Y_i) = 5$ years. Let $T_i = $ transition time from the last job to the current job are random variable, but we are not given $E(T_i)$. How could we solve this part?

**My question:** I don't see the difference between the two questions, as in both cases, the question seems not to account for the transition time. Also, we are not given the average transition time between successive jobs. Could someone please help with the correct interpretation?

Comment: Your answer to part (a) assumes that you're at the end of your current job.

Comment: @Gaffney: I was thinking of a renewal process, where $N(t) =$ the time between successive jobs. So part (b) is asking $N(t)/t$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$. By using the limit theorem, that fraction equals $\frac{1}{5}$. Do you think this is correct? I don't see how to define a renewal process in part (a) btw:p

Comment: So for part (a), my current thought is follows: let $X_n = $ average time spent on current job answered between successive surveys. This is the renewal process, so $E(X_n) = \frac{E(X_n)}{2} + \frac{Var(X_n)}{2E(X_n)} = \frac{5}{2} + \frac{4}{2\times 5} = 2.9$ years. Is this correct?

Comment: Could anyone please give some thoughts to my attempted solution in the comment, or to the original problem?